# w3m window in server

Tags: w3m

I am using proxy for internet with ubuntu server. In server we have to login the internet provider and it should be left idle. In GUI we can minimize the browser. How to minimize w3m ?

Comment: Is w3m being run in a terminal emulator or actual terminal? When using w3m do you have a mouse? Which browser is being minimized? Firefox? Chrome? elinks?

Comment: no mouse..it is running in actual terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to stop the w3m process.

Run the command `jobs -l` to find the w3m process that has been stopped.
Example for me stopping top: `[1]+  3047 Stopped (signal)        top`

Send it to the background with `bg n` where n is the number that jobs -l says for the process.
Example for my stopped top from earlier: `bg 1` and got back `[1]+ top &`

To bring it back to the foreground use `fg 1`